# Copy from one sheet in a workbook and copy to another closed book in another directory

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very big xlsb spreadsheet that my users create a business plan with.  One section of the xlb spreadsheet requires data to be sent to mysql as the spreadsheet also connects to a web interface with other actions.

I am extracting certain rows of data from the xlsb worksheet to be placed in another closed workbook (xlsx) that the users do not have to interact with at all and from that workbook I am importing to mysql and then the web interface takes over.

The problem I am facing is that if the xlsb and closed xlsx files are in the same directory it transfers over ok and I can do an import by allowing the user to click a button in the web interface to select the file but I don't want them to even interact that way as I just know there will be issues...

I want to place an empty and closed xlsx in the local host web root and when the user clicks and active x button on their working xlsb file the vba kicks in and should transfer certain rows of data from the xlsb to the closed xlsx and from there phpExcel (which wont work with xlsb files) 'silently' imports that to mysql and does something with that data.

I just cannot get the transfer to happen if the receiving xlsx file is outside of the users working directory as in the code below. The closed file opens ok but no cell data transfer takes place. It is probably a simple thing I am missing here and have searched high and low but cannot find any hint at what I am doing wrong or NOT doing to get this right... Can anyone please give me a hint as to what is not right?

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

Workbooks.Open "C:\wamp64\www\aircraft\flt_plan_input.xlsx"

Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("flight_plan_input")
 
If ActiveSheet.Range("A1507") <> "" Then
ActiveSheet.Range(" A1506:Q1506").Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats 'xlPasteFormats  'xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If
Workbooks("flt_plan_input.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd suggest you stop relying on `ActiveWorkbook` and `ActiveSheet`.  Assign all books and sheets to variables, and use those to fully qualify all book, sheet and range references.

Comment: Many thanks for the prompt reply Chris. I will look into that as starters